# Strange navigation issues with Swiper.js

Tags: swiper.js

I have added a swiper to our website with the following config:

```
slidesPerView: "auto"
spaceBetween:  30
loop:          true
keyboard:      true
autoplay:      true
```

Everything works fine so far, but the navigation acts very strangely, and I can't figure out why. I tried adding and removing various options, to no avail...

You can see the live swiper here: https://uplink.tech/#profiles

Basically it doesn't loop, if you click on the right arrow below the slides, it stops at some point. And if you click on the left arrow, it jumps an arbitrary number of slides to the left (sometimes 2, sometimes 3 or 4).

Thankful for any tips on how to fix this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated Swiper.js to the latest version (11.0.5) and now it works!

Some bugs related to looping [were fixed in version 11](https://swiperjs.com/changelog) and this seems to have been one of them.

Answer (score 1):

For the loop to work the number of sliders in view need to be not more than half of the total amount of sliders.

e.g If i have a total of 6 sliders it will need to be no more than 3 sliders

Comment: Thanks, Aaron! Is that documented somewhere? In the docs it only says "total number of slides must be: more than or equal to slidesPerView + slidesPerGroup".

https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-loop